# Group by Multiple columns and then count different value of same column

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count, sum

I want to achieve the result which tells me the number of males and females of each disability types in each district.
each district can have multiple disabilities.

So far i have reached  the following query :

```
  SELECT 
  DistrictId, 
  fb.DisabilityTypeId, 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN GenderId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS Male, 
  SUM(
    CASE WHEN GenderId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
  ) AS Female 
FROM 
  Districts d 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN FormAddresses a ON d.Id = a.DistrictId 
  INNER JOIN PeopleForms pf ON a.PeopleFormId = pf.Id 
  INNER JOIN FormBeneficiaries fb ON pf.Id = fb.PeopleFormId 
  INNER JOIN FormPersonalInfos fp ON pf.Id = fp.PeopleFormId 
where 
  a.IsDeleted = 0 
  AND pf.FormTypeId = 2 
  AND d.CityId = 3 
GROUP BY 
  DistrictId, 
  fp.GenderId,
  fb.DisabilityTypeId
```

which gives the following result  :

```
DistrictId  |   DisabilityTypeId    |   Male  | Female
    1       |       2               |   1     |     0
    3       |       2               |   0     |     3
    5       |       16              |   1     |     0
    5       |       20              |   2     |     0
    5       |       20              |   0     |     1
```

But i want to achieve the following result :

```
DistrictId  |   DisabilityTypeId    |   Male  | Female
    1       |       2               |   1     |     3
    5       |       16              |   1     |     0
    5       |       20              |   2     |     1
```

i somehow managed to get the expected result, but that with some complex sub-queries in the select clause  of each gender which i didnt like and was not sure about the performance.

how can i write an efficient query for the desired result that i want?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want the smallest DistrictId for each DisabilityTypeId? Also, provide sample data in terms of INSERT statements, much more useful than asci-art tables.

Comment: @Lennart no its not related to the smallest or largest Ids. the data is a bit complex to provide. we have disabled people in each district, and i want to get the number of males and females for each disability type. is it clear?

Comment: for example in districtId 1 i have X males and Y females that have blindness.

Comment: I dont understand why the blind females in district 3 ends up in district 1. Your query looks correct as far as I can tell, is the some additional information that needs to be taken into concideration?

Comment: @Lennart its not like that the same blind female in district 3 also end up in district 1, they are different, we can have different numbers of males and females that are blind in each district/city.

Comment: the query gives the correct result, but its only that it duplicates the row for each disability type,which give a number for either gender and the other one is 0, like the disabilityTypeid 20 , i want it to be like the one desired result i put.

Comment: You grouping by gender so you get one group per gender. The sample data you posted is misleading

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117646/discussion-between-mahamad-husen-and-lennart).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove gender from `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT DistrictId
     , fb.DisabilityTypeId
     , SUM( CASE WHEN GenderId = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Male
     , SUM( CASE WHEN GenderId = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END ) AS Female 
FROM Districts d 
LEFT JOIN FormAddresses a 
    ON d.Id = a.DistrictId 
JOIN PeopleForms pf 
    ON a.PeopleFormId = pf.Id 
JOIN FormBeneficiaries FB 
    ON pf.Id = fb.PeopleFormId 
JOIN FormPersonalInfos fp 
    ON pf.Id = fp.PeopleFormId 
WHERE a.IsDeleted = 0 
  AND pf.FormTypeId = 2 
  AND d.CityId = 3 
GROUP BY DistrictId
       , fb.DisabilityTypeId
```

Comment: Thank you very much, i didnt know that we can access columns in the select clause that are not grouped by

Comment: In general that is true, but GenderId is part of an aggregate function ( SUM ), so that is perfectly legal.